# How to get to the .minecraft folder without the %appdata% short-hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently using Chunky to render a map. I'm sure I put in the path to my map save, but it won't accept it as a valid directory.

Can someone tell me how to get to the Minecraft saves directory without using %appdata% straight from the File Explorer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **%appdata%** shorthand translates exactly to **C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming**, where **[user]** stands for your Windows username. From here, you can navigate into your .minecraft folder and into the saves directory.

Keep in mind that the AppData folder is hidden by default in File Explorer; you'll need to enable the *Hidden items* option in File Explorer (View menu) if you want to navigate there through the window.

[image: Hidden items]

*Alternatively*, you could just navigate to the directory using the short-hand in File Explorer and copy the current path *from* File Explorer into Chunky. You should get the same as I have said.

Answer (score 3):

Start Minecraft and go to options. Click "resource packs", then click "open resource pack folder". Close to the top, you will see ".minecraft". Click on it to open the folder in File Explorer. You can then copy your current path.